# Setting Main Entry Crashes iWatch App

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, watchkit

My app will compile and run just fine on other devices and simulators. It used to run very well on the watch simulator as well. Out of the blue, I start getting the error:

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

Along with this warning:

```
Check dependencies

Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'Melody Pro WatchKit Extension/Info.plist'.
```

Now I dug around Stack and other places for solutions, and this is what I've tried:

- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting Simulator / Reset all content and settings
- Reinstall Xcode and Simulators
- Reboot machine.
- Double
  checked there are no broken outlets in the Storyboard

What I have realized is causing it: Setting the main entry point in the WatchKit's storyboard. The second I delete it, app compiles fine. The second I add it to any view controller what so ever, the app's build will generate the error.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Full error:

> CompileStoryboard AppName\ Pro\ WatchKit\ App/Interface.storyboard
>       cd "/Users/usersname/Documents/Development/AppName Pro"
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module AppName_Pro_WatchKit_Extension --minimum-deployment-target 8.2 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/usersname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName_Pro-ahibpirzphlviggyowiczbnjgszo/Build/Intermediates/AppName\ Pro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName\ Pro\ WatchKit\ App.build/Interface-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/usersname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName_Pro-ahibpirzphlviggyowiczbnjgszo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName\ Pro\ WatchKit\ App.app /Users/usersname/Documents/Development/AppName\ Pro/AppName\ Pro\ WatchKit\ App/Interface.storyboard

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: @NobodyNada Sure thing, I just updated the OP.

Comment: That's not the error; the error should be listed right under that.

Comment: Also, does the error go away if you remove `Info.plist` from Copy Bundle Resources in your target's Build Phases?

Comment: @NobodyNada Info.plist is actually not included in any of the Copy Bundle Resources areas of my targets

Comment: Weird.  Try a Clean and/or Clean Build Folder and rebuild.

Comment: I've just tried both to no avail :/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue this morning. I was rearranging some code and cleaned up the **Build Phases** / Compile sources list.

By mistake I removed the Interface Controller class from my extension and tried building. Then it gave me this error message.

Fixed it by adding the Interface Controller class back again to the "Compile Sources" list.